# how to manage multiple one-to-many relationships in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following classes:

```
public class A {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Subclass> subA;
}

public class B {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Subclass> subB;
}

public class Subclass {
    /*some data*/
}
```

It gets more complicated:

- each Subclass belongs to either A or B - never both
- each Subclass must belong to someone, otherwise it should be deleted

The problem is that as I see it I must have 2 join-tables, but then how do I automaticly delete the Subclass on removal from A/B?
If you have other ideas for implementation I'll be glad to hear.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add orphanRemoval=true to your @OneToMany

Comment: Just tried it, they don't get deleted from the Subclass table

Comment: Do you have other possible relations, which makes the subclass not being out of relations to other objects?

Comment: no, but I found that with DeleteCriteria it doesn't work, but using the EntityManager does work

Comment: also found that on calling clear() on the Set of Subclasses it doesn't clean the Subclass table